# How to use a field to appear in the dropdown of many2one?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Please help me 
When using many2one I have a combo product names, my question is how to change the content of the combo , ie instead of product I have an identifier.

Thank You

```
class saisir.soumission(osv.osv) 

    _columns = {
        'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre'), # I want use this field to apear in many2one
        'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme'),
        'taxe' : fields.selection([('12','12 %'),('10','10 %')],'Taxe Etablissement'), 
        'observation_s' : fields.text('Observation'),
        'order_line' : fields.one2many('saisir.soumission.ligne','order_id','soumission_id')
        }

class saisir_soumission_ligne(osv.osv):
    _name ='saisir.soumission.ligne'

    def on_change_produit(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id):
        val = {}
        prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id)
        if prod:
            val['prix'] = prod.list_price
            val['garantie'] = prod.warranty
        return {'value': val}

    _columns= {
       'order_id': fields.many2one('saisir.soumission', 'Order Reference'),
       'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Type Engin'),
       'marque' : fields.char('Marque'),
       'prix' : fields.float('Prix Unitaire'),
       }
```

Comment: could you please explore "instead of product I have an identifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `_rec_name` as `'NumOffre'` in your model like this

```
class saisir.soumission(osv.osv)

    _rec_name = 'NumOffre'

    _columns = {
        'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre'), # I want use this field to apear in many2one
        'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme'),
        'taxe' : fields.selection([('12','12 %'),('10','10 %')],'Taxe Etablissement'), 
        'observation_s' : fields.text('Observation'),
        'order_line' : fields.one2many('saisir.soumission.ligne','order_id','soumission_id')
    }
```

Comment: thank you my friend and I am sorry for my bad english

Comment: thank you danidee the solution you gave me with _rec_name works well but still I unable to specify that NumOffre is unique and does not accept two recording with the same NumOffre